# Python setar String onde o cursor estiver

Tags: python, string, cursor, posição-do-cursor

Boa tarde preciso setar uma string onde o cursor estiver parado.

Exemplos: 
- Cursor piscando parado num bloco de notas, jogo uma string no bloco de notas.
- Cursor piscando parado num campo de digitação qualquer, jogo uma string no campo de digitação.

Como posso fazer isso em Python?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você pode utilizar o módulo [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('Stack Overflow em Português é demais!')
```

Isso simulará a entrada do teclado, digitando o texto onde o cursor estiver posicionado.

Comment: Seria isso, resolveu